# Super simple but hard question for a Dart beginner

Tags: dart

I am trying to learn Dart language. Following code seems very straight forward but does not work. I know it may be a foolish question for an expert but for me hard to understand why not ?

```
class Car{

  carFun(){
  
    print("Test");

  }
  
}

main(){

  Car.carFun();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered but I'll give more context.

You need to mark your method as `static`:

```
static carFun(){ ...
```

This makes the method available as a 'Class Method'; right now, as you have defined it, it is an 'Object Method'. This means that you need to make an object out of the class `Car` to be able to use it, which would be something like this:

```
var myCar = new Car();
myCar.carFun();
```

This way you instantiated an object and used a defined method for it. Marking it as static would make this approach not work. This is one of the many differences between a Class and an Object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot to instantiate the class. What I was try to get Car().carFun()

Comment: Basically, everything explained in the link I've provided, so you just copy-pasted. Downvoted, this shouldn't be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: @H4ze Sure, go ahead and do that if you feel that way. In my eyes, your answer was lacking and the link you provided didn't explain the difference between what OP was doing and what s/he should be doing.

Comment: Generally, I'd just comment such questions buf seeing he asked why `Foo.bar();` isn't working. -> because you are missing static on your method, which is full answer to his question. Why is that? Read more on X. Also, this isn't Dart specific question, user is beginner in general. E: Enjoy your points, tho.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your method as `static`. Read more: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods